# How do you selectively import a framework in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, import, frameworks

I have a shared framework that needs to be used by iOS and tvOS, but I want to selectively import a framework for iOS only (CoreTelephony). The swift grammar says you can prepend an attribute, but this doesn't work:

`@available(iOS 10.0, *) import CoreTelephony`

Is this simply not supported? Do I need to subclass just to import the iOS specific framework?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For Swift <= 4.0 you can use the `os()` configuration test function:

```
#if os(iOS)
  import CoreTelephony
#endif
```

You'll have to wrap code that uses `CoreTelephony` as well.

All available tests for `os()` are: `macOS`, `iOS`, `watchOS`, `tvOS`, `Linux`, `Windows`, and `FreeBSD`.

For Swift >= 4.1 you can also use [`canImport()`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0075-import-test.md):

```
#if canImport(CoreTelephony)
  import CoreTelephony
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

[A] framework's build settings IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET as iOS 14

example: (REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538861/9801139)

-> your target build phases

-> link binary with libraries

-> make [A] framework status as optional

In your target

```swift
#if canImport(CoreTelephony)
  import CoreTelephony
#endif
```