# Import submodule with high minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've got a project that supports iOS 12 and also a submodule project that is completely based on iOS 13's CryptoKit and subsequently has the minimum deployment target set to iOS 13.

I'd like to import this submodule for only iOS 13+ targets. Is there any way I can do this and not get the error `Compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'SecrecyKit' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you selectively import a framework in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534854/how-do-you-selectively-import-a-framework-in-swift)

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The suggested `canImport` is a PLATFORM condition and it has nothing to do with OS VERSION.