# Import optional framework

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to import a framework (carthage) which is iOS 10 minimum. My project is iOS 9 minimum and I'd like to keep it. I already did following steps:

- set the framework to be optional,
- all of the classes which are importing it have `@available(iOS 11.0, *)` above the class (due to different reasons I want them to be above iOS 11 not 10),
- added `other linker flag` with `weak_framework FrameworkName`
- The compiler is still not happy with `Module file's minimum deployment target is ios10.0` next to the `import FrameworkName` statement.

What else do I need to do to make my iOS 9 project compatible with such iOS 10 framework? I've looked [at this SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536956/conditionally-import-a-framework-such-as-speech-based-on-ios-version-in-swift) and [this tutorial](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/supporting-older-versions-of-ios-while-including-the-latest-features/) - it seems I did everything required for it to work.

Comment: To the person who voted to close it: maybe it would be useful for the Q&A site to write what isn't clear. I'm not asking without care in 1 sentence and I'm not sure what can not be clear here, so some description how to improve the question would be useful instead of just voting.

Comment: Have you tried to usual suspects? Clean build and buol folder. Delete derived data? (reposting here as it was not intended to be an answer suggestion).

Comment: have you looked into `canImport` with Swift?  It's available in 4.1

Comment: @jacobbullock Yes, I've tried removing derived data, no result. I don't think I've checked it with `canImport` simply because the framework was in Swift 4.0. I've upvoted your comment, as it's a good point for any future readers. Personally, I ended with making an (accepted) pull request with support for older iOS versions. So I'm not sure if that would help. Anyway, as far as I read it's a known issue.