# iOS - Link a framework with higher deployment target than my project's

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, version

I have a Framework that I have linked to my project. The app builds fine. But when I try to import the framework to use in my classes, an error shows that says the framework deployment target is higher than my app's deployment target. Do I have to change my app's deployment target to match that of the framework? Or is there a workaround that lets me keep supporting old iOS versions while still be able to use the framework?

Comment: Have a look at [Frameworks and Weak Linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think about it. The framework could be using features, libraries available in the later deployment of iOS, that aren't in the deployment of iOS you are using. So yes you'll have to change your app's deployment target if you want to use this framework.

Although you can conditionally import a framework based on iOS version [Conditionally import a framework (such as Speech) based on iOS Version in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536956/conditionally-import-a-framework-such-as-speech-based-on-ios-version-in-swift/38538861) but then of course you'll need a solution for the versions of iOS which the framework doesn't work for.

Comment: There are valid use cases for this. For example, my app currently has a deployment target set to iOS 11. For iOS 13 users I am creating new views using SwiftUI. In my SwiftUI code (which is iOS 13 only). Didn't get the conditional import to work, but maybe it is possible.