# How to import a particular framework only if iOS 13 is available?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, ios13

Our app supports iOS 12 and up, however we have two new local frameworks "Jello" and "Wizdom" within the app, but they only support iOS 13 and later (so they can use Combine and SwiftUI).

The app weakly links against Jello, Wizdom, Combine, and SwiftUI. The app's main BaseUI module is what actually imports Jello. BaseUI supports iOS 12 and up so it also weakly links against Jello etc.

However we're running into a problem where BaseUI won't compile because of the error: `Compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'Jello' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0`.

How can I make the import conditional on iOS 13 being available (i.e. don't import it if iOS 13 is not available)?

(So far the only workaround I've found is to create an Objective C wrapper around Jello and access it through that wrapper, but this is awkward and kludgy. I also tried wrapping that whole file with `#if canImport(SwiftUI) ... #endif` however this also doesn't work because it seems that this is just a compile-time check.)

Comment: This is a problem I've been struggling with myself and sadly the only solution I have found was to set the deployment target of my local frameworks to the same version as my app target. However, this forces the use of `@available` in those frameworks even though they'll only be used on iOS, because they have a hard dependency on Combine and SwiftUI. I think fully migrating to Swift Package Manager would be a solution - hopefully with Xcode 12 that will become possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to conditionally import the framework as explained in this post : [Conditionally import a framework (such as Speech) based on iOS Version in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536956/conditionally-import-a-framework-such-as-speech-based-on-ios-version-in-swift/38538861)?
There is a full explanation [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2668-supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices)
However, the main information is that you can define in the framework as optional under the “Targets” section -> "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries" -> "Status" of the framework not available on iOS 12.

You also have to wrap the code using this library with the @available tag.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Yeah, this was the first thing that we tried. It doesn't work.