# Import conditionally a Library/Pod (Firebase) only if device runs iOS 10+

Tags: swift, cocoapods, shared-libraries

I observed [crashes](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8472) of my app when using Firebase/Analytics on devices running iOS 9.
When Firebase is completely removed from the target (I use cocoapods), the app runs stable.

How could I import Firebase module only in case the end device on which my target runs is > iOS 9 ?

I surrounded all calls to Firebase module within " #available(iOS 10, *)", e.g:

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
}"
```

but still the module is imported because of:

```
import Firebase
```

How could I mark this module as "optional" within cocoapods so that it get imported only in case device is running iOS 10+?

PS:

- It seems possible to [mark a library as "Optional"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536956/conditionally-import-a-framework-such-as-speech-based-on-ios-version-in-swift/38538861) inside the target options: "Link Binaries with Libraries" but this only when using Swift Packet Manager. I could not find how to manage this using Cocoapods.