# Conditional import of iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift

My code is for iOS 14 and iOS 15. I need to conditionally import a framework if the users is on iOS 15. How would I do that? Changing the entire project to only be compatible for iOS 15 is not an option.

I tried `@available(iOS 15.0, *) import Package` and

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally import a framework (such as Speech) based on iOS Version in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536956/conditionally-import-a-framework-such-as-speech-based-on-ios-version-in-swift) particularly `#if canImport(YourFramework)`

Comment: `CanImport` check for os type: iOS, macOs et cetera. In your referral link they use what I tried `@available(iOS 15.0, *) import Package` which doesn't work

Comment: `canImport` doesn't check for the OS type -- you pass it a parameter with the name of the package you're looking to import.

Comment: I tried `canImport` doesn't work. See comments of this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64643756/7451631